# How to set cache size in hsql database

Tags: java, database, memory, hsqldb

I am trying to setup the cache size for an existing HSQL database as specified in their website, but i am unable to do so.

Here is what i am trying.

1)Through SQL, i am trying to run the query.

```
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 100.
```

The database is giving me an error that, unexpected files token e.t.c.

2)Through java code while opening up the database connection.
jdbc:hsqldb:file:enrolments;hsqldb.cache_size=100;

But according to their [website](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html) , we cannot change properties of existing database except for only some properties.

Please tell me how can i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to end the statement with a `;` not with a `.` -  `SET FILES CACHE SIZE 100;` works fine for me. Also which HSQLDB version are you using? `set files cache size` did not exist in 1.8

Comment: I am using 1.7, so i believe i cant use the cache size, and cache rows either. But can i set any other property such as cache_size_scale e.t.c through sql or property. I just want to set the cache limit for my Cached type tables. Also if cache size query is availiable after 1.8, can i still use it in 1.7 through property or not, while setting up the JDBC connection. Thanks.

Comment: No. 1.7 is even older than 1.8 - you should check the manual that came with your ancient version. What's the reason for not using the current version?

Comment: Unfortunately, i am working on legacy system which runs on JRE 5 and have been developed using JDK 5. I couldn't find the manual. I have searched a lot. Could you help me out?

Comment: The manual is part of the download archive: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/hsqldb/

Comment: Thanks. I have found the manual online as well now. Here.http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch05.html. But i am confused that,  how these two properties hsqldb.cache_size_scale, and hsqldb.cache_scale work in conjunction to decide the cache limit.

Comment: The online manual is for Version **2.3**, not for 1.7. You have to read the manual that corresponds to the version you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90287/discussion-between-umair-khalid-and-a-horse-with-no-name).